in Firestore, what happens if i try to update an existing document's field when the field doesn't exist?
Let's say I have a collection in Firestore. this collection has some documents, but not all documents have the same fields. for example, one document with ID "house" might have the fields "address" and "color" while another document with ID "car" only has the field "color".
what happens if I have a reference to the collection that contains both documents and I try to update() the "car" document's "address" field (when "car" doesn't have a field "address")?
ex:
// car fields: color (string)
CollectionReference collectionRef = fireStoreService.getCollection("collection");
collectionRef.document("car").update("address", "123 Playground Street");

i've tried searching the documentation (1, 2) and code examples (3) for an answer to this question, but I can't find anything. the best info I could could find was from source #2, which says that:

"If the document doesn't exist yet, the update will fail"

but this doesn't describe what happens if the document exists, but the field does not.


One document with ID "house" might have the fields "address" and "color" while another document with ID "car" only has the field "color".

That's totally fine to have in the same collection documents that contain different fields.

What happens if I have a reference to the collection that contains both documents and I try to update() the "car" document's "address" field (when "car" doesn't have a field "address")?

If you try to update a document, for example, the "car" document that doesn't have an "address" field, then the update operation is valid and it will add the "address" field to the document. On the other hand, when you update a document that already contains the "address" field, the update operation will change the value of the existing field with the new value.
